# Safe to change Website ID and Store ID directly in table customer_entity?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, customer-attribute

Is it safe to change `Website ID` and `Store ID` directly in table `customer_entity`? I can't change it in the backend on the customer information, because it's greyed out. The multistore setup **is not** using shared accounts across the websites, if thats the case.

Customer Account Details Example (Associate to Website disabled):

[image]

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as those customers hasn't placed any orders, I think it should be safer.
Also I would suggest to update via Magento Customer Model instead of SQL.

You can find the sandbox script as below:

```
<?php

/**
 * @author      MagePsycho <info@magepsycho.com>
 * @website     http://www.magepsycho.com
 * @category    Export / Import
 */
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/app/Mage.php');
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');
Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

// Prepare you customer update data
$customersData = array(
    1234 => array( // where 1234 is customerId
        'website_id' => 2,
        'store_id' => 6
    ),
    //...
);

$counter = 1;
foreach ($customersData as $customerId => $_customer) {
    if ($customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId)) {

        $websiteId = $_customer['website_id'];
        $storeId   = $_customer['store_id'];
        $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
        $customer->setStoreId($storeId);
        $customer->save();
        echo sprintf("Customer (%d) with website(%d) and store(%d) successfully changed", $customerId, $websiteId, $storeId) . '<br />';

        $counter++;
    }
}
```